# Выбор базы данных в C#

Tags: c#, база-данных

Нужна встраиваемая база данных для хранения ~30 миллионов записей с достаточно быстрым поиском по ним. Какие существуют и какие можно использовать?

Comment: Что ты понимаешь под встраиваемой БД? БД, которая локально размещает на пк пользователя?